# What do the red souls in the soul gauge mean?

Tags: tales-of-berseria

What does it mean to have a red soul inside the soul gauge?

I know I still can use them for Break Artes, so how are they different from blue souls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple posts, it looks like red souls represent empty parts of your soul gauge. It seems like you are not actually using the red portion to perform Break Artes -- you need at least one soul (the blue ones) to perform these.

From [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/429660/discussions/0/133255708301055299/):

> Red just means they are empty. Blue means that you have the soul. The souls that drop will give you 1 soul up to your max (default of 5, but can be increased to 8). The only thing that "uses" a soul is a Break Soul to my knowledge.
>
> All attacks consumes SG. Each soul represents 30 SG. You can go to artes menu and see the descriptions of the artes. They mentioned how much SG each type of attack consume in the description.
>
> Red only means your SG (Soul Gauge) has been used up. You have to stop attacking so it can recharge. You can defend in the mean time while you are not attacking. SG recharge faster when you dont use your SG till empty. Without SG, you cant chain combos. If keep attacking even when your SG is completely red, you will be very vulnerable to attacks. Enemy can deal stun on you easier. Your attack will also be very weak if you attack when you have 0 SG.

And from [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/429660/discussions/0/133259227523419930/):

> Red means what has been used up by your artes, when all of the souls are completely red (empty SC) and/or when your move requires more SC than what you have left (unless you are at full SC, like only 1 soul), spells will take longer to cast and do less, and your martial/hidden artes will stagger you instead.